# mkmapview on ios versions prior to 3.0

Tags: ios, mkmapview

In my case:

Deployment target: 5.1

xcode version: 4.6.3

I have added MapKit Framework then in the class having viewController i imported the file #import  "mkmapview"

outlet delegates has been properly connect.

but still it's giving error "mkmapview on ios versions prior to 3.0 "

can anyone suggest the solution of this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add the MapKit.framework to you project. To add a framework click on your project, then select the correct target and to o the `Build Phases` tab.
Here you will find the `Linked Binary With Libraries` section, Expand it and add the `MapKit.framework` with `+` button in the left corner.

Then you import the correct library: `#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>`